# How to run my script using wget?

Tags: drupal, wget

I have a URL in my custom `module` which runs a long script. If i call url via `wget` it downloads the page content. It doesn't run the script. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that even though it downloaded the page it would still run the script.

To run without downloading the file use:

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://example.com/path/to/file.php
```

From memory:

-O and the hyphen are redirecting the output so it's not saved to a file.

-q is for quiet

-t is the number of attempts.

You can use man wget to look any more options up.

Comment: Yeah it was running the script, that was my fault. I made some changes in queyr